# How use rounded icon on API 15

Tags: android, android-icons

In my android project:

In my Manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="15"
            android:targetSdkVersion="28" />

<application
        android:name="my_app_name"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/l_icon"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/FacturaTheme" >
```

I can't build project.
I get warning message:

```
Attribute "roundIcon" is only used in API level 25 and higher (current min is 15)
```

I can't increment api level to 25. Because it's requirement to use api 15.
How I can fix this problem with round icon?

Comment: Are you sure that is not a warning?

Comment: Yes it's warning

Comment: @Alexei remove `<uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="15"
            android:targetSdkVersion="28" />` and set `minSdkVersion 15` in `gradle` file it will work

Comment: This project is write on Eclipse. No gradle

Comment: *This project is write on Eclipse* - you are kidding right?

Comment: @TimCastelijns It's very old project. Write before 5 years. So it's was write on Eclipse

Comment: hurry up and migrate it to android studio then

Comment: @TimCastelijns I will migrate to Android Studio. But for now I need to fix this problem on Eclipse.

Comment: *This project is write on Eclipse* - Tempted to flag this as abuse

Comment: If it's a warning, go ahead and ignore it. ✌

Comment: @KevinRobatel But app not start on Eclipse. If I remove android:roundIcon then it success start on Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solution:
Updating minimum sdk to 25 because the `roundIcon` is for Nougat(API 25) and above or remove `roundIcon`